# Ecto query second argument to from must be a compile time keyword list

Tags: elixir, ecto

```
defmodule Arcade.TemplateMedia do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.{Changeset, Query}


 def for_template_id(query \ MODULE, t_id) do
    from u in query,
    where u.template_id == ^t_id
  end



== Compilation error in file lib/arcade/template_media.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) second argument to from must be a compile time keyword list
```

I am trying to use this function to pass into a `Repo.all()`

I don't understand this error. I have the same kind of code in another project with no problem. Is this an Ecto syntax issue between versions? It looks straightforward to me. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you passing as `t_id` there?

Comment: Is that your actual code? It looks like you have typos? Should it look like this: `def for_template_id(query \\ __MODULE__, t_id) do` ?

Comment: *facepalm* yes that is incorrect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you have written, the second argument to `from` is this part: `where u.template_id == ^t_id`. The ArgumentError is trying to tell you to turn that into a keyword list. You can write it verbosely like `[{:where, u.template == ^t_id}]` but most people would write it like this:

```
def for _template_id(query \\ __MODULE__, t_id) do
  from u in query,
  where: u.template_id == ^t_id
end
```

Which is all to say that you forgot the colon after the `where`.